# Pointers in structs changed in kernel function

Tags: cuda

I am trying access an data from array allocated in CUDA. First step was allocate a struct defined by me. After I pass the allocated struct to a kernel function that change the values from the struct. Finally, I pass the struct and the array to a host variables so read them. But actually I am having a problem to read the vector allocated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct x{
    float *y;
    float  v;
}x_t;



__global__ void initTeste(x_t *param){
    param->v = 10;
    param->y[0] = 10;
    param->y[1] = 10;
}


int main(void) {
    x_t *hvar;
    x_t  hvarBackup;

    float *temp = (float*)malloc(10*sizeof(float));

    cudaError_t result;

    cudaMalloc(&hvar , sizeof(x_t) );
    cudaMalloc(&hvarBackup.y, 10*sizeof(float) );

    cudaMemcpy(hvar, &hvarBackup, sizeof(x_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    initTeste<<<1,1>>>(hvar);

    cudaMemcpy(&hvarBackup, hvar, sizeof(x_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(temp, &hvar->y, 10*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%f",(hvarBackup.v)); //here ok
    printf("%f",(temp[0])); //here's the problem

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it like that, because you haven't allocated `y` for the device, hence it will only give you segmentation fault when copying from `y` content to host. Aside of that, you have to allocate `y` for the device with the amount of `10*sizeof(float)`, and this is a truthfully pain in the a** job, especially when your struct becomes a huge container of arrays (and you should always know, that arrays inside structs always have to be avoided in CUDA).

Here's what you can do with the current code

```
int main(void) {

    x_t *h_hvar = (x_t*)malloc(sizeof(x_t));
    x_t *d_hvar;
    float *h_y = (float*)malloc(10*sizeof(float));
    float *d_y;

    cudaMalloc(&d_hvar, sizeof(x_t) );
    cudaMalloc(&d_y, 10*sizeof(float) );

    // Insert the float pointer you allocated in CUDA
    // to the host pointer first, and then copy the whole thing
    // to the device area
    h_hvar->y = d_y;
    cudaMemcpy(d_hvar, h_hvar, sizeof(x_t), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    initTeste<<<1,1>>>(d_hvar);

    cudaMemcpy(h_hvar, d_hvar, sizeof(x_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(h_y, d_y, 10*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    printf("%f",h_hvar->v);
    printf("%f",h_y[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

And that should give you the right value..

Comment: What is the best solution for use of array like the example above?

Answer (score 1):

```
cudaMemcpy(temp, &hvar->y, 10*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

should be

```
cudaMemcpy(temp, hvar->y, 10*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

because hvar->y is already a pointer and you don't want to get the pointer to that pointer.